# Wix, PostgreSQL install, executing Postgresql scripts

Tags: postgresql, wix

I have to make installer that installs Postgresql before our application, makes database and execute some sql scripts against the database.

Now I'm using the Bootstrapper to install Postgresql and then our application and using Wix install sequence I execute SQL script that takes care of the rest.

I'm wondering if there is any way to do it without Bootstrapper? I've read about Wix SqlExtension but can't figure out if it's database independent or if I can install databese server with it...

Answer (score 2):

The WiX SqlExtension is SqlServer specific. However, it shouldn't be that hard to plumb in a Postgresql layer underneath it. IIRC, the actual database calls are pretty abstracted away.

Also, a bootstrapper isn't the correct place to do static configuration either. If this is really configurable data then maybe an entirely separate app launched at the end of install makes sense. But if it's just creating databases, I'd put that in the MSI itself.